# php echo file url and remove dash and .php from the results

Tags: php, arrays, strip

I have a php script that will echo a list of files from a folder and display them randomly on my page.

At the moment it displays the url of the file for example: what-can-cause-tooth-decay.php

Qusetion: is there a way to remove the dashes - and .php from the results so that it would diplay:

**what can cause tooth decay** Instead of **what-can-cause-tooth-decay.php**

```
<?php 

if ($handle = opendir('health')) {
    $fileTab = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $fileTab[] = $file; 
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    shuffle($fileTab);
    foreach($fileTab as $file) {
        $thelist .= '<p><a href="../health/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></p>';
    }
}
?>
<?=$thelist?>
```

Thanks

```
<?php 

if ($handle = opendir('health')) {
    $fileTab = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $fileTab[$file] = strtr(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME), '-', ' '); 
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    shuffle($fileTab);
    foreach(array_slice($fileTab, 0, 10) as $file) {
        $thelist .= '<p><a href="../health/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></p>';
    }
}
?>
<?=$thelist?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

1. Strip the extension from the file,
2. Replace dashes with spaces.

The below should work just fine for you:

```
$fileTab[] = strtr(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME), '-', ' ');
```

See also: [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/strtr) [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/pathinfo)

**Update**

From another answer I've gathered that you additionally wish to select a random set of 10 files to show; the below code should do just that:

```
foreach(array_slice($fileTab, 0, 10) as $file) {
```

Comment: thanks jack but one thing i didn't consider was it echos the results without dash and .php but also strips them from the link also so onclick they go to page not found. oops

Comment: @user1649416 well, instead of '$fileTab[]=' you could write '$fileTab[$file]=' and then use the array keys in the foreach

Comment: Hello, sorry but could you explain that again for a php dummie. add $file to here $fileTab[$file] = strtr(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME), '-', ' '); and then?

Comment: @user1649416 Then `foreach $fileTab as $origFileName => $shortFileName) {`

Comment: sorry but could you pinpoint where i should add that line i have updated my code above

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$str = 'what-can-cause-tooth-decay.php';
$str = str_replace('.php', '', str_replace('-', ' ', $str));
echo $str;
//what can cause tooth decay
```

Comment: Have you tested this with "what-is-php.php"?

Comment: @Jack Interesting that the `.` is ignored. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if ($handle = opendir('health')) {
    $fileTab = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $fileTab[] = preg_replace('/\.php/', '', preg_replace('/-/i', ' ', $file));
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    shuffle($fileTab);
    foreach($fileTab as $file) {
        $thelist .= '<p><a href="../health/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></p>';
    }
}
?>
<?=$thelist?>
```

Comment: you are very good thanks - do you know how to get it to only display 10 files on page load rather than all 119 files that are in health folder?

Comment: -1. Regular expressions are overkill here, especially chained like this.

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill, yes. But I don't think the performance would be a problem in here. My solution is using preg_replace's on simple filenames that are not longer than 30 or 50 characters. IDK, by the size of the input I dont think we will see much difference between strtr or str_replace and this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
$string = 'what-can-cause-tooth-decay.php';
$rep = array('-','.php');
$res = str_replace($rep,' ', $string); 

var_dump($res);
```

ouput:

```
string 'what can cause tooth decay ' (length=27)
```